# R: Changing Display Labels to their "Actual" Values

Tags: r, formatting, label, data-visualization, decision-tree

I am using the R programming language. I used the "rpart" library to fit a decision tree model on some data:

```
  library(rpart)

   car.test.frame$Reliability = as.factor(car.test.frame$Reliability)
    
    z.auto <- rpart(Reliability ~ ., car.test.frame)
    plot(z.auto)
    text(z.auto, use.n=TRUE, xpd=TRUE, cex=.8)
```

As seen here, the labels of the "Country" variable are replaced with "b, e, f, g, h". Is it possible to replace these labels with their actual values (e.g. Korea, Sweden, Mexico, USA, Germany)? I understand that there is a library "rpart.plot" that has more comprehensive visualization capabilities, but I am using a computer that has no USB port or internet access, thus I have no way of downloading this library.

Just using the "rpart" library, is it possible to change the labels from "b,e,f,g,h" to the actual Country names?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I think the issue is more with `text()`. If you run just `z.auto` you can see the country names are there `n=49 (11 observations deleted due to missingness)

node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
      * denotes terminal node

1) root 49 32 5 (0.14 0.14 0.24 0.12 0.35)  
  2) Country=Germany,Korea,Mexico,Sweden,USA 28 18 3 (0.25 0.25 0.36 0.14 0)  
    4) Weight>=3167.5 10  4 3 (0.4 0 0.6 0 0) *
    5) Weight< 3167.5 18 11 2 (0.17 0.39 0.22 0.22 0) *
  3) Country=Japan,Japan/USA 21  4 5 (0 0 0.095 0.095 0.81) *`

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code. That's done by a base R function.

```
levels(car.test.frame$Reliability) < c("Korea", "Sweden", "Mexico", "USA", "Germany")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is there an automatic way to do this for many variables at once?